# Glaring error, unidentified in errata, in Spivak's proof of the change of variables theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

The final inequality looks incorrect to me.  First, there is no reason for the inclusion of boundary points from the rectangles S to increase the integral (consider a negative f).  Second, it seems to me like he wants to say that the final two expressions are equal, but that sort of lemma has not yet been proven, so we don't know that the image of the boundary of the rectangle S under the map g is measure zero.  Am I totally missing something?  Is this special case of the usual lemma (g a c-1 function and S a rectangle in R^n) supposed to be obvious?

[image]

Comment: Step $2-\varepsilon$: it suffices to prove the theorem for non-negative functions.

Comment: Where do you see that language?

Comment: I agree with you that the author implicitely assumes that $f \geq 0$ in the last inequality. However, the general case follows immediately by writing $f$ as the difference of its positive and negative parts. As you pointed out, one could argue that the last inequality is in fact an equality (for $f$ non-negative or not). However, this is not needed at all for the proof.

Comment: Yeah.  That certainly makes it easier.

Comment: Bit how do we know the integrals exist?  Dont we still need that the image of a rectifiable set is rectifiable under a C1 transformation?

Comment: Actually, I think it is supposed to be an equal sign, and it is the case that, given the earlier material, the lemme should be obvious.  The mean value theorem along any line inside a box shows that the image of a square can be fit inside a square proportional to the original.  The lemma follows from the compactness and measure zero of the boundary of the square.  I'm not quite sure if this also tells us both integrands are integrable, though.